# Are all movements and edits bad practice in Vim insert mode?

Tags: vim, vi

I use Vim as a truly multipurpose editor, and so I use it just as much for prose as I do for code. As such, I used to be tempted use it the way I use a (non-modal) word processor: by navigating text and making edits in insert mode. I know this is bad practice, generally, so I navigate by text-objects in normal mode whenever possible, make edits over text-objects (in normal/visual), etc. This makes me so much faster.

But there are still times I want to do light edits in insert that would be slower in normal. Recently I discovered <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> for traversing words in insert mode (which also works in command mode). I've also started using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to delete words in insert mode (usually words I want to take back as soon as I typed them).

But…I've always read that I should avoid the arrow keys as much as possible (in any mode), but this feels like an appropriate use. My question is: **am I building bad habits by using** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> **and** <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd>**?**

Comment: You might be interested in pressing <ctrl> + o whilst still in insert mode, which will let you execute a single normal mode command whilst you are still in insert mode.

Comment: To enter command mode, move a word and go back into insert mode is at least 3 keystrokes. To press shift+arrow is only 2 keystrokes. To enter command mode and delete a word and enter insert mode is at least 4 keystrokes. To Press ctrl+w is only 2 keystrokes. Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving insert mode and doing normal mode navigation should be faster most of the time. If you're tempted to use the cursor keys directly in insert mode, maybe the mode switch is too cumbersome for you. This is especially true with the default location of the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key. Many users map it to left Control or Caps Lock because of that.

There is no right or wrong answer to your question, but the fact that you've asked this question means that there are some doubts on your side. In the end, only you can decide. Keep monitoring yourself, keep comparing and trying different approaches. For example, you could `:map` your cursor keys to `<Nop>` for one Vim session, to wean you off those keys. It might feel clumsy at first, but you need to find out how you'll feel about that at the end of a longer editing session.

Some users are very strict about avoiding cursor keys, or even repetitive primitive motions (like `lllll...` or `jjj...`), and there are plugins that check on or disallow that. Personally, I think it's best to be pragmatic about it. For short tactical edits, I don't mind staying in insert mode and using the cursor keys, especially if I'm currently using other applications in parallel (which often enforce this style of editing). For longer edits that are purely in Vim, I usually exit insert mode often and quickly.

Comment: My biggest problem, I think, is how unintuitive normal-mode edits are. To do what I want, I have to wrangle so many things at once. I even use <s>, <a>, and <A> extensively. It's fast, but I pay a high cognitive price for it. It feels like solving a puzzle, even after using Vim for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Vim allows you to such a high degree of customisation exactly to adapt to everyone's work flow. If it feels faster or better to you, then go ahead and use those shortcuts.

Don't be afraid to test other flows, though. But according to you, you have done it already.